# OpenGL shaders without glut?

Tags: linux, opengl, shader, glut

I'm unable to use GLTools stock shaders in an OpenGL context that was not created by glut.

I'm learning OpenGL from the Superbible 5th edition. The provided `GLShaderManager` and `gltMakeCube` (from GLTools) allow me to render some cubes (`GLBatch::Draw()`) in a window created by glut, using the following code from the Superbible:

```
gltSetWorkingDirectory(values[0]);

glutInit(&count, values);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(1200, 400);

glutCreateWindow("Test");
```

I'm trying to remove the glut code from this program, following the example here http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux:_Programming_Animations_with_GLX_and_Xlib to create a window and attach a context to it. (I'm running Ubuntu)

I've managed to create a window and a context, and to call glClearColor successfully to change the window's background color. However, my cubes are no longer being drawn. The example program linked above works properly, but it doesn't seem to use a shader, instead relying on calls to `glColor3f` and `glVertex3f` to build a cube.

Why doesn't my technique of rendering with GLTools' stock shaders work in a window/context that's not created by glut?

Comment: When you call `glutInitWindowSize()`, does it set the `glViewport()`? might it also call `glOrtho()` or `glFrustum()`? If so, it's setting up a coordinate system that you need to mimic in your own code if you want everything else to draw the same after that. I'd try drawing a 1 unit by 1 unit square or something and see what your scale is after setting things up without glut and see how that compares to with setting them up with glut.

Comment: Shaders vs. Fixed Function is a different thing than Immediate Mode (glVertex calls) vs. Vertex Arrays (glDrawElements / glDrawArray calls).